# How do I log out a user that I authenticated using Socialite for Laravel?

Tags: laravel-5.4, laravel-socialite

I can’t just use `auth()->logout()` because that only logs out the user from the Laravel app and therefore the next time I use say for instance ‘Login using Facebook’ it doesn’t ask me for the Facebook credentials since I’m still logged into Facebook.